# Is it possible to achieve multi column grouping in JqGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I have fifteen columns in the grid and I want to achieve multi level grouping from three columns.  is that possible? I don't want to use tree grid because the columns in the grouping column which will become the rows do not have the columns and it will not make sense to include them.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way right now.  I found this forum post from someone asking for the feature and the response is that it is slated for the "near future".

[Forum Link](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/multiple-grouping/&value=multilevel%20grouping&type=1&include=1&search=1&ret=all)